# Ajax get html on SSL

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("https://www.somesite.com/Securepay/Return.aspx, function(data) {
            alert(data);
                $("#result").html(data);
            });

        });
```

the above code does not return the html. Does anyone have a solution?
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a " missing after the url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("https://www.somesite.com/Securepay/Return.aspx", function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: it was just a typo so it is not the actual problem!

Comment: Then it could be cross-site-scripting, which is not allowed with ajax. Same-origin-policy for ajax-request.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by not returning the HTML Code? If you mean that the alert displays the HTML Code, but the #result item doesn't, try changing the .html( to .text(

Comment: Please add questions as *comments*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have commenting privileges yet. Plus, this isn't just a question. It has an answer too.

Comment: ??? try $.get("http://google.com") and the alert method will be called. But not being called for https

Comment: It's possible that you are prevented from doing this due to cross-site scripting security. HTTPS is meant to be secure, so xss security is stopping you from loading the page. Since you're using get, try setting up a global ajax error function (http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using for the ajaxerror function and what browser you're using?